# How to automatically build client interface for REST api?

Tags: python, rest, python-3.5

Suppose there exists RESTful interface that have following collections with relationships between them represented as a graph in adjacency list form (just for example, this could be json-schema, swagger etc).

```
{
    'countries': {('persons', 'citizens',), ('regions', 'regions')},
    'person': {('country', 'citizenship'), ('companies', 'works_at')},
    'company': {('persons', 'employes'), ('departments', 'departments'), ('offices', 'offices')},
    'department': {('persons', 'employes')},
    'office': {('person', 'employes')}
}
```

```
the key is the name of the collection, the value is a set of relationships. Where relationship is a pair `(collection, relationship name)`

I thought about automating a task of building client interface and make nice client api for that.
The simplest solution I could think of is this (would work in python 3.6 as kwargs should be sorted)

```
def build_url(**path):
    # ommiting lots of details, but the basic idea is this
    if is_path_exists(path):
        return '/'.join(map(str, chain.from_iterable(path.items())))
```

I thought for some time for a workaround against that in python 3.5 kwargs aren't sorted and couldn't find one, so this was probably the wrong way to do it, but in python 3.6 client code could even be as simple as this.

`get(build_url(country='some_country', person='john', company=None))`
And this would return all companies that john from some_country works.

This solution have one more flaw. It doesn't give user any information about what entities exists in api.

So, how would you achieve this? Maybe there are libraries for that already?

EDIT1. Yes, I know about swagger. I've just learned that it has some code generation capabilities, but that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to generate code, I want to create it dynamically using metaprogramming maybe. Also although I know java, generate python code with java is a bad idea, as not every python programmer could change this generator.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - https://github.com/zalando/connexion

Comment: @SRC I need client library to query (for now, maybe post, put etc later), not the server. This isn't clear enough in my post? Maybe I can improve it somehow?